# How to import pywikibot?

Tags: python, pywikibot

I have installed pywikibot and set up the config as described in the instructions. However when I put "importpywikibot" at the top of my script it says "No module named pywikibot". Do I have to install pywikibot somewhere special?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed `pywikibot` then you can't import it. You need to

```
pip install pywikibot
```

on the command line and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the installation guide didn't include that.

Comment: @TechnTom Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)

Comment: Also please fix the installation guide if it was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

First change "importpywikibot" to "import pywikibot"
You need to create your python file in the "core" directory otherwise it will say "no module named pywikibot".

After installing pywikibot, you'll find core directory in C=> users=> your username => core

And do it from your cmd prompt. It showed error when I used vs code but worked fine when I run the program in the cmd.